# phpexcel,laravel formulas not working on loaded file

Tags: laravel-4, phpexcel

I have a test excel file and I try to update a cell and recalculate results, but it doesnt work? Even explicitly seting the formula through interface on that cell

```
$prevI11 = $reader->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I11')->getCalculatedValue();

$reader->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I11','=G11');
$reader->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G11',89.0);
$newformulaI11 = $reader->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I11')->getValue();
$newI11 = $reader->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I11')->getCalculatedValue();

dd($prevI11.'|'.$newformulaI11.'|'.$newI11);
```

Initial value in excel file for I11 is - 2
The results is `string(8) "2|=G11|2"` which obviously is just an original value from loaded file

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHPExcel caches the results of a calculation so that it doesn't need to recalculate again if your request the calculated value for the same cell multiple times.

This means that if you retrieve the calculated value for a cell (`I11` in your case), then change the value of a cell that would affect the calculation and retrieve the calculated value again, you'll be retrieving the previous result from the cache rather than recalculating it.

You can disable this caching behaviour using

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($reader)->disableCalculationCache();
```

or flush the cache at any point using

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($reader)->clearCalculationCache();
```

**EDIT**

As a way of testing this, the PHPExcel calculation engine has a built-in debugger:

```
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('G11', 2)
            ->setCellValue('I11', '=G11');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


function testFormula($sheet, $cell) {
    $formulaValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getValue();
    echo 'Formula Value is ' , $formulaValue , EOL;
    $expectedValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getOldCalculatedValue();
    echo 'Expected Value is '  , ((!is_null($expectedValue)) ? $expectedValue : 'UNKNOWN') , EOL;

    $calculate = false;
    try {
        $tokens = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($sheet->getParent())
            ->parseFormula($formulaValue, $sheet->getCell($cell));
        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo EOL;
        $calculate = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'PARSER ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , EOL;

        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo EOL;
    }

    if ($calculate) {
        try {
            $cellValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();
            echo 'Calculated Value is ' , $cellValue , EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , EOL;
            print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($sheet->getParent())
                ->getDebugLog()->getLog());
            echo EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'CALCULATION ENGINE ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , EOL;
            print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($sheet->getParent())
                ->getDebugLog()->getLog());
            echo EOL;
        }
    }
}


$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)
    ->getDebugLog()->setWriteDebugLog(true);

testFormula($sheet,'I11');


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('G11', 89.0);

PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)
    ->clearCalculationCache();

testFormula($sheet,'I11');
```

Running this without the line to clear the cache, I get the following output

```
Formula Value is =G11
Expected Value is UNKNOWN
Parser Stack :-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => G11
            [reference] => G11
        )

)

Calculated Value is 2
Evaluation Log:
Array
(
    [0] => Testing cache value for cell Simple!I11
    [1] => Simple!I11 => Evaluating Cell G11 in current worksheet
    [2] => Simple!I11 => Evaluation Result for cell Simple!G11 is a floating point number with a value of 2
)

Formula Value is =G11
Expected Value is UNKNOWN
Parser Stack :-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => G11
            [reference] => G11
        )

)

Calculated Value is 2
Evaluation Log:
Array
(
    [0] => Testing cache value for cell Simple!I11
    [1] => Retrieving value for cell Simple!I11 from cache
)
```

Showing that the second time that the calculated value for cell I11 is retrieved, it doesn't recalculate but retrieves the cached value

With the line to clear the cache, I get

```
Formula Value is =G11
Expected Value is UNKNOWN
Parser Stack :-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => G11
            [reference] => G11
        )

)

Calculated Value is 2
Evaluation Log:
Array
(
    [0] => Testing cache value for cell Simple!I11
    [1] => Simple!I11 => Evaluating Cell G11 in current worksheet
    [2] => Simple!I11 => Evaluation Result for cell Simple!G11 is a floating point number with a value of 2
)

Formula Value is =G11
Expected Value is UNKNOWN
Parser Stack :-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => G11
            [reference] => G11
        )

)

Calculated Value is 89
Evaluation Log:
Array
(
    [0] => Testing cache value for cell Simple!I11
    [1] => Simple!I11 => Evaluating Cell G11 in current worksheet
    [2] => Simple!I11 => Evaluation Result for cell Simple!G11 is a floating point number with a value of 89
)
```

Showing that the cache is cleared, and the calculation engine is forced to recalculate the formula taking into account the new value of cell G11

Comment: That didnt help. Put disableCalculationCache, then clearCalculationCache in all possible combinations - no changes to a formula cell - always an old value

Comment: One more thing - the calculation works if the result cell is empty (not used in original excel)! This renders any work on excel files as templates - useless...

Comment: This only works on new phpexcel sheets, and does not work on cells which are occupied by loaded excel, sorry

Comment: The PHPExcel object neither knows nor cares whether it was created as a new spreadsheet or loaded from a file

Comment: A prove - is that moving result to an unoccupied cell works and on an occupied - doesnt. Its not really an argument

Comment: yeah, run away and dont look back while flipping those burgers.. Man.. you should really learn listen - dont assume a random guy like me is against you or your cool library. Anyway thanks for your efforts

Comment: Provide me with a specific block of code and a template file that will demonstrate this problem, and I'll take a look; but I've not been able to replicate it so far either creating an empty PHPExcel object and populating it through a script, or by loading a file